# In NumPy, what is the difference between [::-1][::-1] and [::-1, ::-1] 2d array indexing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wanted to reverse a 2d array and but got two different results while using `[::-1][::-1]` and `[::-1, ::-1]` indexing. Here is a sample below. I can't quite understand how it is differently interpreted.

```
values = [
    [5, 6, 5, 5, 8, 9, 9], 
    [9, 5, 1, 4, 5, 9, 7], 
    [3, 9, 6, 2, 1, 2, 3], 
    [1, 7, 6, 7, 1, 7, 5], 
    [2, 1, 3, 8, 7, 8, 8], 
    [2, 9, 3, 6, 4, 6, 4]
]
x = np.array(values)
reverse_2d_1 = x[::-1][::-1]
reverse_2d_2 = x[::-1, ::-1]
```

```
[[5 6 5 5 8 9 9]
 [9 5 1 4 5 9 7]
 [3 9 6 2 1 2 3]
 [1 7 6 7 1 7 5]
 [2 1 3 8 7 8 8]
 [2 9 3 6 4 6 4]]
```

```
[[4 6 4 6 3 9 2]
 [8 8 7 8 3 1 2]
 [5 7 1 7 6 7 1]
 [3 2 1 2 6 9 3]
 [7 9 5 4 1 5 9]
 [9 9 8 5 5 6 5]]
```

Comment: With the first one, you are only performing the operation on the 1st dimension. 1st you reverse the 1st dimension and then reversing it again to the original. With the second one, you are performing operations on both dimensions. If you want to get the 2nd one with seperate operations, you can do `x[::-1][:, ::-1]`

Comment: Note that *indexing* reduces dimensionality, so nested indexing operates on different axes (cf. something like `x[-1][-1]`) but *slicing* maintains the dimensionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example, the two slices are resolved separately, because each slice is a separate operation. So the first `[::-1]` will flip the array vertically, and then the second `[::-1]` will flip it vertically again, leaving it as it started.

In the second example, the slices are resolved together, and each slice operates on the corresponding axis. So the first `::-1` will flip vertically, and the second `::-1` will flip horizontally.

If you find it easier to understand, you can also call `np.flip(x, (0, 1))` to flip along the given axes.